# X server is now disabled. Restarted MDM error after forceinstalling Radeon driver

Tags: boot, drivers, radeon, nomodeset

AMD Radeon HD 6550D

--

Tl;dr:
I was an idiot for forceinstalling a driver and none of the normal options to solve my problem help anymore. Thanks!

--
Background:
Whenever I pressed the 0 button my screen would flash -> tried fixing this by updating drivers via the 'driver manager' in LinuxMint Cinnamon/rafaella? (newest version, had updated a day before).

The error got worse, so I reverted the change. Then I couldn't boot anymore.

I did the following I found on the internet:

```
Sudo su
Xorg configure
cp /root/xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf
startx
```

This did not work, and eventually I followed another guide into the GRUB, pressed e, looked for 'quiet splash'  and added

```
radeon.modeset=0 (which didn't work) and tried nomodeset.
```

This worked and got me back into my computer, but still no driver installed.
Went to amd website, found the driver and did an install, it wouldn't install because something along the lines of: fglrx was already installed (they said either remove it, or do a force install).

I didn't know how to remove it, so I force installed.
The install came back saying there was an error, and that I needed to reboot.

The error I am getting now at boot is:

```
'the x server is now diabled. Restart MDM when it is configured correctly'
```

Now though, none of the above (conventional) options work anymore and I have spent about 5 hours trying to fix this.

Can anyone help? There is work on my computer I would rather not lose :)
PS. Would also be interested in learning how to save all my files and put them on a new version of linuxmint. If that is a quicker fix.

Thanks a ton for reading!